# Caret position al final en jformattedtextfield

Tags: java, jtextfield, cursor

Tengo un **jFormatted textfield** con una máscara numérica.
Esto hace que al hacer clic en el campo, el cursor se posicione donde el usuario ha hecho clic, en lugar de al inicio, ya que está rellenado de *placeholders*.
¿Cómo puedo modificar esto, manteniendo la restricción numérica?

código:

```
        MaskFormatter formatter;
        txtNum_1 = new JFormattedTextField();
        try {
            formatter = new MaskFormatter("#########");
            formatter.install(txtNum_1);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        txtNum_1.setHorizontalAlignment(JFormattedTextField.LEFT);
        txtNum_1.setCaretPosition(JFormattedTextField.LEFT);  // No funciona
```

Answer (score 0):

la solución es añadir un focus listener de esta forma:

MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("####");
JFormattedTextField fText = new JFormattedTextField(mf);
fText.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.PERSIST);
fText.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

```
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
        {
            fText.setText(fText.getText().trim());
        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
```